# When saving to csv using pandas, I get two same databases instead of two separate ones

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am doing some exercise as part of a GIS and Python Course that I am undertaking individually through Git. The exercise is analysis of weather data from two weather stations. Their IDs are spelled USAF and have codes: 29980 and 28450. I have created a "selected" dataframe from the existing one and from that one, I need to select all rows into a variable called kumpula where the USAF code is 29980 and to a variable Rovaniemi where the USAF code is 28450.

I have done this:

```
kumpula = selected.loc[selected['USAF']==29980]
rovaniemi = selected.loc[selected['USAF']==28450]
```

That is good. Now, I need to save the kumpula and rovaniemi DataFrame into 'Kumpula_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv' and 'Rovaniemi_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv'. I also need to separate with comma and use only 2 decimals in the floating point number.

Here is my code:

```
kumpula = "Kumpula_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv"
selected.to_csv(kumpula, sep=',', float_format="%2f")
rovaniemi = "Rovaniemi_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv"
selected.to_csv(rovaniemi, sep=',', float_format="%2f")
```

This code should work. But, both of the files are the same. They are for rovaniemi, e.g., USAF code is 28450. Am I somehow overwriting "Kumpula_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv".

Comment: you write two times the same `selected` - maybe you should save `kumpula.to_csv()` and `rovaniemi.to_csv()` but don't assing filenames to variables `kumpula`, and `rovaniemi` - use filenames directly in `to_csv()` or use different variables for filenames.

Comment: When I try to save directly, it gives me an error:    

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-35be08348857> in <module>
      3 selected.to_csv(kumpula, sep=',', float_format="%2f")
      4 rovaniemi = "Rovaniemi_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv"
----> 5 rovaniemi.to_csv(rovaniemi, sep=',', float_format="%2f")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv

Comment: as I said - DON"T assing filenames to `kumpula` and `rovaniemi` because there are your dataframes - so you remove dataframes and you have only strings with filenames. You have to use `kumpula.to_csv("Kumpula_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv", ... )`

Comment: you can see problemif you use `print()` after every line of you code to display values in variables.

Comment: Thank you. It is solved now. I just now realized what you were saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your code as:

```
kumpula_df = selected.loc[selected['USAF']==29980]
rovaniemi_df = selected.loc[selected['USAF']==28450]
kumpula_df.to_csv("Kumpula.csv", sep=',', float_format="%2f")
rovaniemi_df.to_csv("rovaniemi.csv", sep=',', float_format="%2f")
```